# What do I supply to Moq for my Generate() method's delegate parameter?

Tags: c#, delegates, moq

I've got a legacy system that I'm in the midst of refactoring.

I have an object substantially as follows:

```
public class SUT
{
  public delegate SaveStuff(SomeObject obj);
  public void Generate(SaveStuff saver)
  {
    // Do stuff
    var obj = new SomeObject();
    saver(obj);
  }
}
```

I'm very new to using Moq, and want to count the number of times 'saver' is called.

I've seen a number of examples here on SO, but am stumped on how to setup the test

```
[Test]
public void TestDelegateCall()
{
  var sut = new SUT();
  // Prepare SUT's State...

  var callCount = 0;
  sut.Generate(??);
  Assert.AreEqual(callCount,2);
}
```

What goes where the ?? is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know that you need to use MOQ here, I believe you could just do the following and take advantage of anonymous methods and closures :)

```
var callCount = 0
sut.Generate(obj=>callCount++);
```

If that does not work, then you can just use the explicit delegate setup:

```
var callCount = 0
SaveStuff actionCounter = delegate(SomeObject obj)
    {
        callCount++;
    };
sut.Generate(actionCounter);
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to compile, but it got me where I need to go. `SaveStuff actionCount = delegate(SomeObject obj) { callCount++; };` worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sweet!  After changing to your simple example, R# helped me make it even cleaner to `sut.Generate( obj=> { callCount++; });` and that helped me solve another problem.  You just upped my understanding significantly.  Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer so that it should work with the anonymous method if you want it to be less lines. But, I have also updated the code to use the older delegate approach. I tested both, and both should work. You dont even need the brackets from your last comment :)